# Can't figure out which JS callback to use for asynchronous Facebook login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to allow asynchronous facebook login with javascript. I'm using the same code everyone uses:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'XXX',
    channelUrl : '//' + host + '/channel.html',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    // ajax call to find or create account
  });
}
```

However, this ONLY fires the callback if you weren't previously logged into Facebook.

The auth.authResponseChange event works as a login button callback, but it also fires every time the page loads. That's not very useful if the button wasn't actually clicked.

What I really need is a callback that fires *when and only when* the login button is clicked.

**EDIT:**

Everything is consistent if I have my site's Sign Out button sign you out of Facebook, but that's just irritating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked and answered: [Facebook Login Button callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883187/facebook-login-button-callback-function)

Short answer: Simplify. Use a callback on an image button instead of some fancy .fb-login element + subscribing to an event.